# Need to convert back slashes to forward slashes in github action work flow

Tags: windows, powershell, cmake, path, github-actions

In my actions yml file, I set an environment variable pointing to the root directory for my ctest input image files (I run ctest to test an image codec decompressor, and these are the input images).

```
env:
  DATA_ROOT: ${{github.workspace}}/data
```

On windows, this is gives me something like `c:\Foo\Bar/data`, and I would like to convert it to
`c:/Foo/Bar/data`

I can do the conversion in PowerShell:

```
$temp = ${DATA_ROOT}
$pattern = '[\\]'
$temp = $temp -replace $pattern, '/'
```

but how do I then reset `${DATA_ROOT}` to equal `$temp` ?

I want subsequent steps to use the new ${DATA_ROOT} .

Comment: You can use steps inputs and outputs. `echo "DATA_ROOT=$temp" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT` and then `env: DATA_ROOT: ${{ steps.dataroot.outputs.DATA_ROOT }}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why this is tagged CMake, but you can set environment variables in GitHub Actions by writing a line containing `NAME=VALUE` to `$GITHUB_ENV`.

From the GitHub Actions [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-environment-variable):

> ```
> echo "{name}={value}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
> ```
>
> Creates or updates an environment variable for any actions running next in a job. The action that creates or updates the environment variable does not have access to the new value, but all subsequent actions in a job will have access. Environment variables are case-sensitive and you can include punctuation.
>
> **Example**
>
> ```
> steps:
>   - name: Set the value
>     id: step_one
>     run: |
>         echo "action_state=yellow" >> $GITHUB_ENV
>   - name: Use the value
>     id: step_two
>     run: |
>         echo "${{ env.action_state }}" # This will output 'yellow'
> ```
>
> **Multiline strings**
>
> For multiline strings, you may use a delimiter with the following syntax.
>
> ```
> {name}<<{delimiter}
> {value}
> {delimiter}
> ```

---

For a CMake solution, if you have a path with potentially mixed slashes, you can use [`file(TO_CMAKE_PATH)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#to-cmake-path)

```
file(TO_CMAKE_PATH "c:\\Foo\\Bar/data" path)
message(STATUS "path = ${path}")  # prints: path = c:/Foo/Bar/data
```

Note that this function assumes the incoming path is a *native* path for the platform on which CMake is running. So on Linux, an input with a drive letter would be invalid (the `:` would be interpreted as a `PATH` separator and converted to a `;`)

Answer (score 7):

Note this is hurting me right now with `${{github.workspace}}` using `\` path separators on windows, breaking any "run" actions using the bash shell. So this doesn't work;

```yaml
defaults:
  run:
    shell: bash

jobs:
  build:
    steps:
    - name: Configure CMake
      run: cmake -B ${{github.workspace}}/build
```

A workaround is to put single quotes around `'${{github.workspace}}/build'` which prevents bash from treating the `\` path separators as escapes.